# ToolStripSplitButton splitter issue

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I have a form with `ToolStrip` and I placed on it `ToolStripSplitButton`.

```
    toolStrip1.BackColor = Color.White;
    toolStrip1.GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden;

    splitButton.Image = PlusPic;
    splitButton.Size = new Size(30, 30);
    splitButton.Visible = true;
    toolStrip1.Items.Add(splitButton);
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

But for some reason I have to use custom renderer for `ToolStrip`.

```
class ToolstripCustomRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer { }

toolStrip1.Renderer = new ToolstripCustomRenderer();
```

And after I set `Renderer` it changed look of `ToolStripSplitButton`. It independs of which methods I override in `ToolstripCustomRenderer`. So my `ToolStripSplitButton` looks different:

[image]

And I want to get rid of splitter which appears. But I don't have a clue how to do this.

Comment: Wrong base class, derive from ToolStripProfessionalRenderer instead.

Comment: Perfect! It was so easy. Make your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Surely you know how to complete the Q+A you started now??  Just post the solution yourself and mark it as the answer to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is just to use `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` as parent class for custom renderer. (Hans Passant)